# Unstack aDictionary in pharo

Tags: dictionary, smalltalk, pharo

I have an object like `a Dictionary('CMFireAutomataModel'->a Dictionary('nbAshes'->193 'nbFires'->851 ) )` and I would like to have something like `Dictionary('nbAshes'->193 'nbFires'->851 )`.

I don't know how to "unstack" the first dictionary.

Comment: It's quite unclear what all the conditions of your problem are. But at face value, if your original dictionary is called `d`, then you could just do `d values first`.

Comment: Perfect ! It's exactly what I expect !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have a `Dictionary` whose keys are `Strings` and its values are `Numbers` or `Dictionaries` of the same sort (i.e., with keys that are strings and values that are dicts or numbers). What we want is a way to "promote" or "unstack" all string keys and numbers to the mother dictionary.

```
unstack: aDictionary
  | dict |
  dict := aDictionary class new.
  aDictionary keysAndValuesDo: [:k :v | | d |
    v isNumber
      ifTrue: [dict at: k put: v]
      ifFalse: [
         d := self unstack: v.
         dict addAll: d associations]].
  ^dict
```

Note that I've used `aDictionary class new` to make sure the method answers with a `Dictionary` of the same kind (e.g., an `IdentityDictionary`, etc.).

Note also that the method could go in any class. I haven't put it in `Dictionary` because I don't think this is general enough (even though that would have simplified the code a little bit)

Comment: i am not sure what the intent of operation, but your example implementation using if statement instead of direct dispatch. (Do not ask - tell).
Instead, just implement #unstackTo: aDictionary method
so, Object will implement it as no-op, and Dictionary will implement it as adding all its key-value pairs to provided dictionary.
But as i said, it is unclear what intent of the author, so i'm not sure it is worth to do at all.

Comment: @IgorStasenko, I concur. Note however that I didn't want to add methods to `Object` or `Dictionary` because the operation is too specific to a particular need (not explained in the question). More knowledge could reveal that there is no need to unstack anything in the first place. (See also the last sentence of my answer)